# Issue in check Null condition using linq query

Tags: c#, linq, null

I used joins and select query for passing dynamic values for the particular entity, Some fields are null in db. So i check the condition `!=null` condition but the whole select statement is throwing error if i use that field.

**My code as follows,**

```
@placementId is as input value

IEnumerable<Submission> sub= from cc in confirmedCarrierRepository
    join cs in carrierSubmissionRepository on cc.ConfirmedCarrierID equals cs.ConfirmedCarrierID
    where cr.PlacementID == placementId
    //orderby c.panel is missed

    select new SubmissionEntity
    {
        PlacementId = placementId,
        //The ComissionId is null in db,
        CommissionId = cs.CommisionID.HasValue ? cs.CommisionID.ToString() : string.Empty
    }
```

Another way:

```
CommissionId= cs.CommisionID!=null ? cs.CommissionID : new int()
```

I can't understand why. Even i check null condition also how could the whole select won't work. Please help me to find out.

Comment: what is  new int(), this is a value type, then initialize like a reference type, also what does "cs.CommisionID.HasValue" do, that also doesn't seems to be correct. I can understand cc, which is confirmedCarrierRepository, but what is cs, you need to provide complete code

Comment: If you want to exclude the null cs.CommisionID, then use a where clause, instead of what you have done, since this will still select all the values, just that Null values will be replaced by Empty string

Comment: Edited my question. But I am checking the filed whether it is null or not. How could it is checked by where condition. If any value it should return but no error return.

Comment: What is your aim, i understand to remove the values with "cs.CommisionID" as null, please confirm

Comment: My aim is if cs.CommisionID is null, just return null / empty string. The whole select statement is not working. Error is throwing like Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: null or empty for "SubmissionEntity" or the "CommissionId". Also if "CommissionId" is null then "HasValue" will lead to Null reference Exception

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in an `IQueryable` world (meaning your linq must generate a db query), then `ToString()` is not allowed.

You may use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127(v=vs.110).aspx)

I'm not sure that `HasValue` is allowed either (you may just try), but `!= null` is certainly allowed

Assuming `CommissionId` is an `int?` in your entity :

The "string" way

```
CommissionId = cs.ComissionId != null ? SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cs.CommmissionId) : string.Empty
```

The "int" way

```
CommissionId= cs.CommisionID ?? 0 // or default(int), but not new(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use c# [coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator

```
 CommissionId = (cs.CommisionID ?? 0).ToString();
```

Comment: do you want also to display null comisssion id as empty?

Comment: @PoliDev can you show the definition of this class `SubmissionEntity` ?